# notified when screen is unlocked even if application is closed in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

is there any way to bind delegate to unloack event so that i can get notified when the phone screen is unlocked .

i have tried `Oscured` and `Unobscured` event. But it don't notify if the app is not running.

is there something like  `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT` in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows Phone, when an app is not in foreground, it is either closed or in a dormant state (meaning that all the application threads are stopped and no processing takes place).

Therefore, there is no way of knowing that the screen is being unlocked when the app is not in foreground.